# ConvNet : Validation Loss not strongly decreasing but accuracy is improving

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, multilabel-classification

Using `TensorFlow` I've build a simple `CNN` for classification.  It has the following definition:

```
Input Tensor : 32,32,1 Grayscale Image
1 Conv Layer 3x3x32
Relu Activated
2x2 Max Pooled
128 FC1
43 FC2 # 43 classes
```

Full code can be found on this [notebook on github](https://github.com/autojazari/gtsd-solution/blob/master/Solution-Cleaned.ipynb)

The `validation loss` and `accuracy` at `Epochs` **100**, **1000**, **2000** are

```
epoch 100 validation loss 3.67, validation accuracy 12.05%
epoch 1000 validation loss 3.234, validation accuracy 57.63%
epoch 2750 validation loss 3.111, validation accuracy 69.25%
```

Unless I've misunderstood or have a bug somewhere, the network is learning.  However the validation loss is has only decreased very slightly.

What does that mean? How can I use this information to improve the network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic mistake in TensorFlow: you shouldn't apply a softmax on your output and then `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`.

The operation `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` expects unscaled logits (i.e. without softmax). From the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/nn/classification#softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits):

> WARNING: This op expects unscaled logits, since it performs a softmax on logits internally for efficiency. Do not call this op with the output of softmax, as it will produce incorrect results.

Comment: The funny thing is that I had read that before! Thank you very much, works great now!

Comment: Haha first thing I check when people have weird loss in TensorFlow